# TreeListView control

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-controls

I need to implement TreeList control same as in Process Explorer.
I am quite newbie in GUI and did not write such complicated controls.

As I see in Process Explorer, there is a TreeListWindowClass, which contains children:
2 headers, 3 scrollbars (one of them is invisible?) and 1 static (place between visible scrollbars).
As I understand, main control draws all items inside itself.
Also I did not found mfcxxx.dll in attached dlls.

Question 1: what framework it’s better to use?
There are: MFC, WTL, plain WinAPI …
I took a look at this implementation http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/classes/article.php/c13167 and was confused with > 8000 lines of code in cpp file with huge structures (one of them contains 80 members).
It is plain WinAPI (and C without ++).
I definitely want to use OOP style. =)

Question 2: 
What is the high-level design of this control should be?
Can you explain without deep details how does this control should be designed?

My limitations: C++, VS10, OS: Vista and higher.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no TreeList control in those class libraries.  Mark Russinovich made his own.  8 KLoc sounds about right, it isn't a simple control.  It is a popular offering for 3rd party tool vendors.  Finding one written in C++ is going to be tricky.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a native one, publicly available for sale, written in C++. I've seen plenty of managed ones though.

Comment: Hans, the problem is not 8KLoc, but old style of programming. I have not much knowledge yet about creating own controls. So I prefer to learn creating them in a modern way (using classes, not plain C). GrahamS gave me excellent starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this recently and used the Multi-Column Tree View from http://www.mimec.org/articles/mfc/mctree

[image: Screenshot of Multi-Column Tree View]

It is fairly basic, but it met my needs and is fairly compact. It provides a `CColumnTreeView` class which is a sub-class of `CView` - so it works correctly with the standard CDocument/CView pattern of MFC.

Comment: You're welcome! Only potential gotcha I have encountered is that the `CView::OnInitialUpdate()` method will call `yoursubclass::OnUpdate()` before `CColumnTreeView::OnInitialUpdate` has completed - so the result of `GetTreeCtrl()` is not valid on the first call to your `OnUpdate` - easy to protect against by adding `if (GetTreeCtrl().m_hWnd == NULL) return;`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the exact equivalent of Process Explorer's "Tree List View" from [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)'s source (which is a *lot* better IMHO.)

Comment: Thanks for link. It will be useful for several other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is a library that offers a fully functioning [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html) that looks like it meets the requirements of your program.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a Tree control, NOT a treelist control. A treelist control is the combination of a tree control and a listview or grid control.

Comment: the screenshot looks like that, but qtreewidget supports this as well http://www.civilnet.cn/book/embedded/gui/qt4/images/settingsviewer.jpg

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has some excellent treelist controls, however they are written in C#. However you can target them using C++/CLI, or managed C++. So I'm not sure if you are able to make your app managed. So perhaps it might not be so helpful.

As for free treelist controls, I try to stay away from them, due to bugs, and lack of support.